# Branched user permissions for editing content types

Tags: 7, nodes, users

What is the best way to implement the user permissions (in brackets) in following pattern with Content Types as follows:

- Parent (editable by owner & tagged parent-editors)

  - Name
  - Description
  - ...
  - Tagged Parent-editors (users)
- Child (editable by owner & tagged child-editors & tagged parent-editors

  - Name
  - Description
  - ...
  - Tagged Child-editors (users)
  - Entity reference: Parents
- SubChild (editable by owner & tagged child-editors & tagged parent-editors)

  - Name
  - Description
  - ...
  - Entity reference: Childs

Where "..." are some other fields, dependant on the ContentType.

Parent A editors must not be able to edit Parent B

I've looked into the Module [Node Access User Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) which seems like it may do this potentially, but I was wondering if there is a standard way of doing this or whether anybody has some prefered/suggested Modules for doing this or even a completely different solution!

Comment: there's no standard way to it. use the module ;)

Comment: Has anybody done something like this before and can suggest the best module to do it with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try [Node Privacy by Role](http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole) module.
First create three roles Parent Editors, Child Editors, Subchild Editors
Then while creating a node you will be asked about the permission to edit the node.
But this might not help you when you want to protect nodes per user.

There is also another module [Taxonomy Access Control Lite](http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite) which governs access to nodes based on the taxonomy terms applided to nodes.
In this you can create terms for Parent Editors, Child Editors and Subchild Editors

Apart from that there is also good discussion here:

http://drupal.org/node/24073

http://drupal.org/node/285369

Comment: Both the modules that you suggested are not in active development, and neither have a recommended download for D7 so I probably can't use them for this project I'm afraid!